# How to redirect to another page in mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a timer in my mvc4 controller I want to redirect to another page if condition satisfies in Timer_Elapsed event. The Timer_Elapsed event is-

```
 private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (MavenifyEntities db = new MavenifyEntities())
        {
            timer.Stop();
            string tempId = TempData.Peek("TempId").ToString();
            bool Ispresent = db.DataSyncs.Any(d => d.TempId == tempId);
            if (Ispresent)
            {
                // redirect to another view
            }
            else
            {
                timer.Start();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unclear what your asking. Its the client which is responsible for making a request to the server which returns a view. What are you trying to do with this?

Comment: I have to redirect to another page i.e."ShowData.cshtml" when if statement is executed.

Comment: actually this timer is checking for a perticular value in database after every 2 seconds. when this value is found I have to open a new page.

Comment: Side note: it is very unlikely the code shown will do anything close to what you may want to achieve... Spelling out your actual goal (not the way how you think you may achieve it) could help with finding solution. In any case you should provide [MCVE] - at very least show how "timer" is wired up and how it relates to requests.

Comment: Makes no sense. A browser makes a request to your method and returns a response. What does the timer have to do with anything?

Comment: Actually i am new to mvc4 so please suggest me the way how to implement this scenario.

Comment: We do not know what your trying to implement. And Alexei noted, you need to spell out what your trying to achieve.

Comment: I have a cshtml page in which a Qr code is shown. when any mobile scans the Qr, it calls a web service to insert the value to database. I have to check continuously that if this value is present in database. if this value is present. I have to show related info in another page.

Comment: @VIVEK This logic should be on your browser. The browser should continually ask the server 'Has the value been inserted yet?' If the response is yes, create the redirect. Otherwise, wait a bit and ask again. In short, though, this polling should be implemented on the client.

Comment: Ok Rob. Thank you so much. Gonna implement it

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Response.Redirect** like following:

```
Response.Redirect(Url.Action("YourAction", "YourController"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think best solution is that doing this job in JavaScript.

For example like this:

```
redirectURL = "http://x.com/ShowData";
function timedRedirect() {
//Check Server for redirect
    setTimeout("location.href = redirectURL;",redirectTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return RedirectToAction("ActionName","ControllerName");
```